# Undesired vim <tab> on insert mode

Tags: vim

I'm encountering an unexpected behavior from the tab key.  I want to type the corresponding chars for my snippets and use the tab key to initialize them.  The problem is that everytime I use the tab key on insert mode it types the following string, "**context**." (without the quotations and period.)  The current tab setup does not allow my snippets from triggering and is undesired behavior.

I guess I somehow managed to mess up my tab key by careless macro use or recording.  Since I'm not an advanced user, I don't really know where to start troubleshooting this.  I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Use your snippet-expander plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Was this issue happening before you installed the snippet plugin?
Maybe you misconfigured the snippet file if you were making changes.

Comment: After some manual troubleshooting I was able to identify the problem was coming from the supertab plugin.  Once the plugin was deleted, the tab was working as expected.  Thank you both for the comments.